# "running a fever" origin

Tags: etymology, idioms

> I'm running a fever/temperature.

I have a student who likes to ask where idioms come from. Since the meanings are not literal, it is challenging for her to remember them. It often helps her to attach a story or explanation to an idiom, even if it is only folk etymology.

I've not had any luck searching on EL&U or in any dictionary for the origins of the phrase. It's always present in dictionaries but for etymology just refers the reader to `run`, which never explains the specific meaning in `running a fever/temperature`.

If anyone knows where the phrase actually originates, it would be helpful, but even a non-referenceable* etymology would be useful.

---

*i.e. heard from some guy down the pub; learnt a long time ago but I forget where; made-up; etc.

Comment: You're asking for the bending of the site rules with your appeal for hearsay answers. From meta: 'Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions ... [require] that opinion be backed up with facts and references'

Comment: Well, the question itself is not subjective, at least in my opinion (which is both subjective and biased! Ho ho). Anyway, I would of course prefer to know the real source of the phrase. But the ultimate purpose to which the answer will be put does not demand accuracy, only plausibility, hence my allowance of `even a non-referenceable` theory. I certainly didn't mean it to come across as "anything goes".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the actual entymology of the phrase, but 'to run' means in this case 'to continue to have', so while the fever is being maintained it's 'running'.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Can you think of another example of 'run' with the meaning 'to continue to have'?

Comment: 'The meter is running' (in a taxi). This is not to 'continue to have' per se, but more to continue in a particular state (which is probably more appropriate than using 'to continue to have' with respect to your original question).

Comment: If we allow 'continue in a given state', which seems very reasonable, "I'm running late today" is another example, this time a link verb usage.

Comment: I really like the idea of thinking of it as a linking verb. I think that might work for my student.

Answer (score 1):

I always considered this to be something of a misplaced ownership of the word *running*.

It is not the person who is *running* a fever but rather the person has a fever and it is the fever that is running, *running it's course*; eventually the fever will complete it's *run* and the person's temperature drops to normal again (or they are dead).

Comment: So are you saying a semantic shift has occurred?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Dunno really, it could mean _running_ as in _managing_ but I'm just saying that I always think of _running a fever_ as the fever running it's course rather than the person with the fever having any input to 'the running' (managing).

Comment: 'Run / running' have many senses, not all of which imply an agent subject (Agent: deliberately performs the action). John ran quickly / John ran the bar //// Time ran slowly / The river ran swiftly / My blood ran cold / The car is running well / The fever ran its course. It's trying to sort out the evolutionary pathways that's tricky.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Assuming that _running a fever_ is actually an idiom then I'm sure we'll all be put straight in good time, it's not like it's an old phrase where the origins may have been lost.

Comment: That's what idioms often are.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The more I think about it the less likely it is that it really is an idiom. _running a fever_; the _a fever_ bit isn't idiomatic and (as you pointed out) _run_ has so many possible uses/meanings that one of them will almost certainly be the right one. If _running a fever_ was used to mean _to find someone very attractive_ as in _I'm running a fever for her_ that's more like a proper idiom.

Comment: If you're serious about tackling what idioms are argued to be, Rosamund Moon's 'Fixed Expressions and Idioms in English: A Corpus-based Approach' is, I'd say, required reading. 338 pages. AHD lists 'run a temperature/fever' under the 'Idioms' heading after the standard definitions for 'run'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ha! No, I'm not serious about it, certainly not 338 pages serious !

Comment: So you realise that not all the comments on the site are equally well grounded in objective research.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's what the down vote button is for isn't it?

Comment: "Only people who have read over 300 pages of Moon are eligible to vote on questions tagged 'idiom' "?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I might get through it tonight then, it's either that or Dead Sushi (they have the same strict rules for voting on some movie genres at movies.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

[Ngran](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run%20a%20fever&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,run%20a%20fever;,c0) shows that its usage started to become popular at the beginning of 1900.

I have found the following reference :[to run a fever](http://www.englishdaily626.com/slang.php?100)

Etymology:

'Run' has many meanings. In this phrase, 'run' means 'to continue to have', so 'run a fever' refers to a person maintaining a 'fever' (a high body temperature).

Comment: Is Ngran the older version?